# JPA and MySQL: Knowing if start and end dates are aligned in a group by clause

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I am using Spring, Hibernate (using JPA) to run a query.

My table has the following data:

```
------------------------------------------------
| building_id | cost | start_date | end_date   | 
------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 23   | 2015-03-02 | 2015-04-05 |
------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 25   | 2015-04-02 | 2015-05-05 |
------------------------------------------------
| 2           | 23   | 2015-03-01 | 2015-04-09 |
------------------------------------------------
| 2           | 25   | 2015-04-02 | 2015-05-05 |
------------------------------------------------
```

My query should:

1. Sum up the cost for each building
2. Get the minimum of start_date and max of end_date
3. Let me know that for each group of building whether the start_date and end_dates were same or not.

So far I have written the following query:

```
SELECT sum(ct.cost), min(ct.startDate), max(ct.endDate) from ConcernedTable ct where ct.buildingId in :buildingIds AND ct.startDate >= :startDate and ct.endDate <= :endDate and group by YEAR(ct.endDate), MONTH(ct.endDate)
```

As you can see using the above query I can meet my first 2 requirements. But I don't know how to get whether the building start and end dates were same or not.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

a way is check if the diff betwen max(date) and min(date) is 0 and show

```
    SELECT 
          sum(ct.cost)
        , min(ct.startDate)
        , max(ct.endDate) 
        , case max(ct2.startDate) - min(ct2.startDate) when 0 the KO else OK END
    from ConcernedTable ct 
    inner join ConcernedTable as ct2 on ct.buildingId  = ct2.buildingId
    where ct.buildingId in :buildingIds 
    AND ct.startDate >= :startDate 
    and ct.endDate <= :endDate 
    and group by YEAR(ct.endDate), MONTH(ct.endDate)
```

Comment: But it might happen that the start_date have the same dates but the end_date do not. In that case, the query will not return the correct result.

Comment: explain better .. what do you need about  the startdate and enddate .. from you question seems you don't want in a period that the two date are the same  ... the period is the month or is another ?

Comment: Lets consider 3 buildings whose start and end dates are as follows:
1. 2015-03-02 | 2015-04-05
2. 2015-03-02 | 2015-04-05
3. 2015-03-03 | 2015-04-06

Building 1 and 2 have the same start and end date but building 3 has a different one. In this case the result for date alignment should be false

Comment: in this case you can't  use group by  Year , month for check the date difference ... then the date difference is not for month but assolute.. right?

Comment: Yes the date must absolute if we are considering their alignment within a group (which was found out using the Year(ct.endDate) and Month(ct.endDate))

Comment: I have update the answer with an inner join .. but i'm not sure  ...let me know